# how to let users post code snippets using backticks and display code using google code preetify?

Tags: javascript, css, code-snippets, forum

I have a forum in my website where people can ask questions and add reply, mostly about web development that includes posting `code` snippets.

I have used forums including stackoverflow where we can use backticks to display code. How do i implement the same functionality in my site?

here is my site : http://kaloraat.com/questions/how-to-redirect-user-after-password-reset-in-laravel

Also I want to use google code prettify but i have to assign class name to each block of code using class like this `class="prettyprint"` which is impossible since I am not writting articles. Users will be posting code throught the Q&A in forum.

Is there a simple way of doing it? I would like to at least implement a feature to use backticks to display code that way i dont have to use tinymce which is not user friendly andalso might be a security risk.

Comment: you need some code, for sure - do you have any idea about any part of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to display code the way they look in sublime text full of colours, currently if you visit the link I have posted to my site, all you see is code colored in red, bootstrap default. its not readable. Code will be submitted by users using the textarea which will also contain plain text.

Comment: `if you visit the link` - yeah, no that's not going to happen, nor is it relevant at all

Answer (score 0):

Three backticks(```) is markdown syntax which defines a snippet of code. So to use the the backticks syntax you need a markdown parser like `marked` (https://github.com/chjj/marked), which will parse the markdown string into html.

#### Example

````
var markdownString = "```var foo = 'bar';";
var output = marked(markdownString);

console.log(output); //<pre>var foo = 'bar';</pre>
````

#### Suggestion

Html

```
<body>
    <textarea id="content" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
    <hr />
    <h3>Output</h3>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('content');
var outputElement = document.getElementById('output');

inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var html = marked(e.target.value);
    outputElement.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/yezinorari/edit?html,js,output

#### Adding code high lighting:

Html

```
<head>
    <!-- highlight.js css-file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.6.0/styles/default.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="content" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
    <hr />
    <h3>Output</h3>
    <div id="output" class="prettyprint"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Added highlight.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('content');
var outputElement = document.getElementById('output');

inputElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    var html = marked(e.target.value);
    outputElement.innerHTML = html;

    //for each node which is of type pre element
    //add code highlight.
    outputElement.childNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        if(node.tagName && node.tagName === 'PRE') {
            hljs.highlightBlock(node);
        }
    });
});
```